# i need to create a view to save information on the top 2 highest paid people

Tags: sql, sql-server

well here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE ROOM
(
RoomCode INT PRIMARY KEY,
RoomName NVARCHAR(20),
Established INT
)

CREATE TABLE STAFF
(
StaffCode INT PRIMARY KEY,
StaffName NVARCHAR(20),
Birth NVARCHAR(20),
Gender NVARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE BONUS
(
RoomCode INT FOREIGN KEY (RoomCode) REFERENCES ROOM(RoomCode),
StaffCode INT FOREIGN KEY (StaffCode) REFERENCES STAFF(StaffCode),
Paid INT
)

INSERT INTO ROOM VALUES
(01,N'Phòng quản lý',2001),
(02,N'Phòng nhân sự',1999),
(03,N'Phòng hành chính',2002)

INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES
(001,N'Nguyễn Hoàng', N'24/05/2003',N'Nam'),
(002,N'Văn Hoàng', N'24/05/2003',N'Nữ'),
(003,N'Vũ Hoàng', N'24/05/2003',N'Khác')

INSERT INTO BONUS VALUES
(01,001,1000000),
(02,002,9000000),
(03,003,8000000)
```

I'm new to SQL programming language so any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What is your question here? You've dumped some code (not in a code block/fence) and told us you're new to the language (which isn't relevant), however, you've not asked a question in your question. We can't help you when we don't know what you're asking, nor what the difficulty is you're having achieving your goal.

Comment: A view doesn't save any values. It returns values from base tables.

Comment: Side note, as well, it looks like you're storing date (and time) data in a string-based data type, and the format of the string you are using is ambiguous. This is a seriously fatal and fundamental flaw. Use a date and time data type.

Comment: What's wrong with a `SELECT TOP (2) ... ORDER BY Paid DESC`